# How to find missing dates from a table group by each user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show missing dates from a table on which a user do not perform any tasks.My table with some data is

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks
    ([Name] varchar(50), [UserId] int, [TaskDate] datetime)


INSERT INTO Tasks
    ([Name], [UserId], [TaskDate])
VALUES
    ('mickel',1, '2012-08-06 00:00:00'),
    ('mickel',1, '2012-08-07 00:00:00'),
    ('mickel',1, '2012-08-011 00:00:00'),
    ('mickel',1, '2012-08-013 00:00:00'),

    ('Joseph',2, '2012-08-06 00:00:00'),
    ('Joseph',2, '2012-08-08 00:00:00'),
    ('Joseph',2, '2012-08-09 00:00:00'),
    ('Joseph',2, '2012-08-12 00:00:00'),

    ('Shan', 3, '2012-08-07 00:00:00'),
    ('Shan', 3, '2012-08-08 00:00:00'),
    ('Shan', 3, '2012-08-10 00:00:00'),
    ('Shan', 3, '2012-08-12 00:00:00')
```

A want to display output in which each row shows name of each user and comma separated list of missing dates.

Comment: can you give some examples

Comment: You question is very vague - can you give an example of what the output *might* look like?  Do you want this in SQL, or in C#?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: first of all, you'll need at least a start date to check from

Comment: I want the result in sql query

Comment: I have find the missing dates but cannot group them by user.

Comment: Can you show how you got the missing dates?

Comment: See if this helps: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/08/29/tsql-filling-missing-date-range/

Comment: so you want missing dates from the user first login date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65c13/2) creates an inline table value function:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   name = 'ExplodeDates'
                AND type = 'IF' )
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ExplodeDates;
END;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ExplodeDates 
(
    @StartDate  datetime, 
    @NoDays     integer 
) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT  TOP ( @NoDays )
            DateVal = DATEADD( DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY s1.object_id ), @StartDate )
    FROM    sys.all_objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects s2
);
GO
```

Then uses a CTE to generate the results and `FOR XML PATH` to stuff the final columns.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  u.Name, u.UserId, x.DateVal
    FROM (  SELECT  StartDate = MIN( t.TaskDate ),
                    NoDays = DATEDIFF( DAY, MIN( t.TaskDate ), MAX( t.TaskDate ) )
            FROM    dbo.Tasks t ) p
    CROSS APPLY dbo.ExplodeDates( p.StartDate, p.NoDays ) x
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT Name, UserId
                FROM    dbo.Tasks ) u
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Tasks t
        ON  u.Name = t.Name
        AND u.UserId = t.UserId
        AND x.DateVal = t.TaskDate
    WHERE   t.Name IS NULL
        AND t.UserId IS NULL ) 
SELECT  f.Name, f.UserId, LEFT( f.MissingDates, LEN( f.MissingDates ) - 1 )
FROM (  SELECT  c1.Name, c1.UserId, MissingDates = (
                    SELECT  CONVERT( VARCHAR( MAX ), DateVal, 112 ) + ', '
                    FROM    cte c2
                    WHERE   c2.Name = c1.NAME
                        AND c2.UserId = c1.UserId
                    ORDER BY c2.Name
                    FOR XML PATH( '' ) )              
        FROM    cte c1
        GROUP BY c1.Name, c1.UserId ) f
ORDER BY f.UserId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this query:

```
select 
p1.userid,
  ( SELECT  Convert(varchar(max),taskdate, 121 ) + ' and ' 
       FROM tasks  p2
      WHERE p2.userid = p1.userid
      ORDER BY NAME
        FOR XML PATH('') ) AS NameValues from tasks p1 group by userid
```